# creating dynamic form in rails with grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic

please I need help here on how to properly implement [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select). I need to implement it in an app and I haven't gotten a good lead to understand how it works. I used `grouped_collection_select` but I need to change the key and value pair.

Answer (score 0):

In `grouped_collection_select` you can use `option_key_method` and `option_value_method` (6th and 7th option) to set your key,values:

`option_key_method` - called on a child object of a member of collection, returns a value to be used as the value attribute for its `<option>` tag (i.e key)

`option_value_method` -called on a child object of a member of collection, returns a value to be used as the contents of its `<option>` tag.(i.e. value)